# KeyStroke button ENTER disable NewLine

Tags: java, swing, button, newline, enter

i have this this code for a button (test) that is associated with ENTER key.

```
contentPane.add(test);
    getRootPane().getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW).put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("released ENTER"), "press");

    this.getRootPane().setDefaultButton(test);
```

when i press the ENTER key, it works fine, but does the NewLine command as well. How could I disable the NewLine feature??
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is kind of unclear, do you want to activate the button when the focus is in a textfield/textarea by pressing Enter but NOT write a new line in the textfield/textarea ?

Comment: Yes. The code works but i don't want the new line in JText Area.

Comment: Basically you need to consume the event in case it's the Enter key that is stroked. Something like this :

JTextArea area = new JTextArea();

area .addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {

   public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
      char c = e.getKeyChar();
     if (c == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER)) {
         e.consume();  // ignore event
      }
   }
});

Comment: I tried but doesn't work. 
Alternately, how can I put the cuursor on the last char in this string input? 

String input = jTextAreaINPUT.getText();

Comment: Which Enter key do you use, the one of the numeric pad or the other one ? Try with the one you didn't try, maybe you have to add a clause per Enter key.

Answer (score 0):

I solved addinng:

```
String input = jTextAreaINPUT.getText();
input = input.replace("\n", "");
```

in this way, I take only the first line and not the second empty line.